# Prevent Scrollbar Appearing on transform: translate with React-Spring

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transforms, react-spring

Whenever I add a `translate()` CSS function to a `react-spring` `useTransition` hook `from` or `leave` property where the element will go out of the viewport, I am getting a vertical/horizontal scrollbar.

```
const transitions = useTransition(show, null, {
    from: {
        opacity: 0,
        transform: "translate3d(500px,0px,0px) scale(1)"
    },
    enter: {
        opacity: 1,
        transform: "translate3d(0px,0px,0px) scale(1)"
    },
    leave: {
        opacity: 0,
        transform: "translate3d(0px,-500px,0px) scale(1)"
    },
    config: {
        duration: 3000
    }
});
```

[image]

I know this is expected and the general solution is to add `overflow: hidden` to the `body`.

But I am unsure how to do this while the animation is occurring? As I don't want to add `overflow: hidden` to the `body` at all times as I do need access to the scrollbar in certain pages, just not when the animation has initiated?

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ee19d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to try it out for yourselves

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the class of the body with document.body.classList.add and remove. For example you can add one more useEffect, like this:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (show) {
      document.body.classList.add("animation");
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove("animation");
    }
  }, [show]);
```

And of course you must define your style to the class:

```css
.animation {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

See the example here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-scroll-fj6t8

It is just a crude example. You can add the classList.remove to the return of the useEffect. Or you can try adding it to the onRest callback of useTransition if you want to remove it when the animation stopped.

Comment: but, is it going to affect future css rules? can be problematic ?

Comment: @KickButtowski If you remove the class after using the animation, then it will probably not affect them.

Comment: How do you suggest it?